# Can't get data from server using axios get response

Tags: vue.js, http, axios, get, response

I'm trying to get json data from server with axios get response.

```js
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        films: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      getFilms() {
        const path = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/films';
        axios.get(path)
          .then((res) => {
            this.films = res.data.films;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.getFilms();
    },
  };
</script>
```

But at result i have empty list. How can i fix this? Or mb there is another way to get data from server.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any obvious (to me) errors.  I would start by confirming that ```res.data.films``` contains the data you think it does.  Console.log it and/or call the API in your browser address bar.   You may only need to access ```res.data```.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, error was on server side (CORS did'n allow to connect from another ip)